# Remove duplicates by value from list in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Given two lists composed by several "objects" in the following format: `(name id)` how can I get the objects from the first list that do not match by name the second one?

Expected output:

```
(remove-duplicates-by-name
  '((Oliver 1) (Charlie 2) (Oscar 20))
  '((Oliver 2)(Charlie 3)))

((Oscar 20))

(remove-duplicates-by-name 
  '((Oliver 1)) 
  '((Oliver 2)(Charlie 3)))

()

(remove-duplicates-by-name 
  '() 
  '((Oliver 2)(Charlie 3)))

()
```

**Edit:**

**Output order matters.** Example:

```
(remove-duplicates-by-name 
  '((Oliver 1) (Charlie 2) (Oscar 20) (Daniel 30)) 
  '((Oliver 2)(Charlie 3)))
```

Correct output: `((Oscar 20)(Daniel 30))`

Incorrect output: `((Daniel 30)(Oscar 20))`

Comment: Your examples do not correspond to the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two hacky solutions.

```
(defun remove-duplicates-by-name (l to-remove)
  ;; low performance with large to-remove lists but fine with short
  ;; ones
  (loop for e in l
        unless (assoc (car e) to-remove)
        collect e))

(defun remove-duplicates-by-name (l to-remove)
  ;; high performance with large to-remove lists but consy and
  ;; probably slow with short ones
  (loop with dups = (loop with dt = (make-hash-table)
                          for e in to-remove
                          do (setf (gethash (car e) dt) t)
                          finally (return dt))
        for e in l
        unless (gethash (car e) dups)
        collect e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your examples have nothing to do with *duplicates*, but everything to do
with [Lists as Sets](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_abb.htm).

E.g.:

```
(set-difference '((Oliver 1) (Charlie 2) (Oscar 20)) '((Oliver 2)(Charlie 3)) :key #'car)
==> ((Oscar 20))

(set-difference '((Oliver 1)) '((Oliver 2)(Charlie 3)) :key #'car)
==> ()

(set-difference '() '((Oliver 2)(Charlie 3)) :key #'car)
==> ()
```

Comment: It would be a set if order does not matter, however it does. Imagine if I had an element in front of Oscar like (Daniel 30), I don't want an output of ((Daniel 30)(Oscar 20)).

Comment: I suggest that you rewrite your question and add examples. Right now it is confusing.

Comment: Your answer is almost fine with my question, however sets do not maintain order and order matters in the output. However thanks for your suggestion.